# Configurar unittest no vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Não estou conseguindo configurar o recurso de teste unitário do Visual Studio Code. A extensão fica informando que nenhum teste foi encontrado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha configuração de argumentos está no modo default, ou seja:

```
  #// Arguments passed in. Each argument is a separate item in the array.
  "python.unitTest.unittestArgs": [
    "-v",
    "-s",
    ".",
    "-p",
    "*test*.py"
  ],
```

E a estrutura do meus projeto é essa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, a extensão não está localizando o modulo **guardtest** dentro da pasta **tests**.

Segue o [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/unit-testing) da descrição do recurso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido!

Como meus testes não ficam do diretório raiz do projeto, precisei informar o diretório no arquivo de configuração, então ficou assim:

```
    "python.unitTest.unittestArgs": [
    "-v",
    "-s",
    "tests",
    "-p",
    "*test*.py"
]
```